# Change html CSS style property with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I implement this JavaScript block with jQuery?

```
var x = document.getElementById("name");
if (x.style.backgroundColor == "black"){
//do this
}
```

I get stuck at this point:

```
if ($("#name").css() == ???){
//Do this
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work!

```
var color = $("#name").css("background-color");

if(color == "black"){
    //do this
}
```

OR

if you would like it in one line:

```
if($("#name").css("background-color") == "black"){
  //do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the native version.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('name');
if (el.style.backgroundColor == 'black') {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

```html
<span id="name" style="background-color:black">Hello World</span>
```

And here is the jQuery version:

**Note:** The jQuery [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method will return the computed CSS value, so you will need to change `black` to `rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

```js
if ($('#name').css('backgroundColor') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="name" style="background-color:black">Hello World</span>
```

But you should really check for the existence of a class and not rely on a particular style rule.

```js
if ($('#name').hasClass('spoiler')) {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

```css
.spoiler {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="name" class="spoiler">Hello World</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the background of element with id `name` is black, i recommend you to check HEX code, because `.css('background-color')` returns string `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

```
var hexDigits = new Array
        ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function hex(x) {
    return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
}

if(rgb2hex($('#name').css('background-color')) == '#000000') {
    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#name").css("background-color") == "rgb(0,0,0)"){
  // Do the needful
}
```

- `$("#name")` is the ID Selector: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
- `.css()` is a Get/Set that can get a style property by name: https://api.jquery.com/css/

Example from jQuery CSS page:

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("#result").html("That div is <span style='color:" +
      color + ";'>" + color + "</span>.");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<span id="result">&nbsp;</span>
<div style="background-color:black;"></div>
<div style="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);"></div>
<div style="background-color:#00ff00;"></div>
<div style="background-color:#00f;"></div>
```